# Can't get kubernetes to pass my tls certificate to browsers

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes

I've been struggling for a while trying to get HTTPS access to my Elasticsearch cluster in Kubernetes.

I *think* the problem is that Kubernetes doesn't like the TLS certificate I'm trying to use, which is why it's not passing it all the way through to the browser.

Everything else seems to work, since when I accept the Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate, the requests go through as expected.

In my attempt to do this I've set up:

- The cluster itself
- An nginx-ingress controller
- An ingress resource

Here's the related yaml:

- Cluster:

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
      creationTimestamp: 2018-08-03T03:20:47Z
  labels:
      run: my-es
  name: my-es
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3159488"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/my-es
  uid: 373047e0-96cc-11e8-932b-42010a800043
  spec:
      clusterIP: 10.63.241.39
  ports:
      - name: http
  port: 8080
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 9200
  selector:
      run: my-es
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
  status:
      loadBalancer: {}
  ```
- The ingress resource

  ```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
      annotations:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-origins: http://localhost:3425 https://mydomain.ca
      https://myOtherDomain.ca
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  creationTimestamp: 2018-08-12T08:44:29Z
  generation: 16
  name: es-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3159625"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/es-ingress
  uid: ece0071d-9e0b-11e8-8a45-42001a8000fc
  spec:
      rules:
          - http:
  paths:
      - backend:
  serviceName: my-es
  servicePort: 8080
  path: /
  tls:
      - hosts:
  - mydomain.ca
  secretName: my-tls-secret
  status:
      loadBalancer:
          ingress:
              - ip: 130.211.179.225
  ```
- The nginx-ingress controller:

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2018-08-12T00:41:32Z
    labels:
      app: nginx-ingress
      chart: nginx-ingress-0.23.0
      component: controller
      heritage: Tiller
      release: nginx-ingress
    name: nginx-ingress-controller
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "2781955"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/nginx-ingress-controller
    uid: 755ee4b8-9dc8-11e8-85a4-4201a08000fc
  spec:
    clusterIP: 10.63.250.256
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    ports:
    - name: http
      nodePort: 32084
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      nodePort: 31182
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
    selector:
      app: nginx-ingress
      component: controller
      release: nginx-ingress
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: LoadBalancer
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - ip: 35.212.6.131
  ```

I feel like I'm missing something basic, because it doesn't seem like it should be this hard to expose something this simple...

To get my certificate, I just requested one for mydomain.ca from godaddy.

Do I need to somehow get a certificate using my ingress resource's cluster IP as the common name?

It doesn't seem possible to verify ownership of an IP.

I've seen people mention ways for Kubernetes to automatically create certificates for ingress resources, but those seem to be self signed.

Here are some logs from the nginx-controller:

This one is talking about a PEM with the tls-secret, but it's only a warning.

```
{
 insertId:  "1kvvhm7g1q7e0ej"
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "fluentd-gcp-v2.0.17-5b82n"
  container.googleapis.com/namespace_name:  "default"
  container.googleapis.com/pod_name:  "nginx-ingress-controller-58f57fc597-zl25s"
  container.googleapis.com/stream:  "stderr"
 }
 logName:  "projects/project-7d320/logs/nginx-ingress-controller"
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-08-14T02:58:42.135388365Z"
 resource: {
  labels: {
   cluster_name:  "my-elasticsearch-cluster"
   container_name:  "nginx-ingress-controller"
   instance_id:  "2341889542400230234"
   namespace_id:  "default"
   pod_id:  "nginx-ingress-controller-58f57fc597-zl25s"
   project_id:  "project-7d320"
   zone:  "us-central1-a"
  }
  type:  "container"
 }
 severity:  "WARNING"
 textPayload:  "error obtaining PEM from secret default/my-tls-cert: error retrieving secret default/my-tls-cert: secret default/my-tls-cert was not found"
 timestamp:  "2018-08-14T02:58:37Z"
}
```

I have a few occurences of this handshake error, which may be a result of the last warning...

```
{
 insertId:  "148t6rfg1xmz978"
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "fluentd-gcp-v2.0.17-5b82n"
  container.googleapis.com/namespace_name:  "default"
  container.googleapis.com/pod_name:  "nginx-ingress-controller-58f57fc597-zl25s"
  container.googleapis.com/stream:  "stderr"
 }
 logName:  "projects/project-7d320/logs/nginx-ingress-controller"
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-08-14T15:55:52.438035706Z"
 resource: {
  labels: {
   cluster_name:  "my-elasticsearch-cluster"
   container_name:  "nginx-ingress-controller"
   instance_id:  "2341889542400230234"
   namespace_id:  "default"
   pod_id:  "nginx-ingress-controller-58f57fc597-zl25s"
   project_id:  "project-7d320"
   zone:  "us-central1-a"
  }
  type:  "container"
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"
 textPayload:  "2018/08/14 15:55:50 [crit] 1548#1548: *860 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:442"
 timestamp:  "2018-08-14T15:55:50Z"
}
```

The above logs make it seem like my tls secret isnt working, but when I run kubectl describe ingress, it says my secret terminates.

```
aaronmw@project-7d320:~$ kubectl describe ing
Name:             es-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          130.221.179.212
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.61.3.7:8080)
TLS:
  my-tls-secret terminates mydomain.ca
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /   my-es:8080 (<none>)
Annotations:
Events:  <none>
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the pod, they might tell you what is not being loaded correctly. If you could post those here.

Comment: @Crou Thanks for the response, added logs from the nginx-controller. Let me know if those don't seem relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out!

What I ended up doing was adding a default ssl certificate to my nginx-ingress controller on creation using the following command

```
helm install --name nginx-ingress --set controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate=default/search-tls-secret stable/nginx-ingress
```

Once I had that, it was passing the cert as expected, but I still had the wrong cert as the CN didn't match my load balancer IP.

So what I did was:

- Make my load balancer IP static
- Add an A record to my domain, to map a subdomain to that IP
- Re-key my cert to match that new subdomain

And I'm in business!

Thanks to @Crou, who's comment reminded me to look at the logs and got me on the right track.